# angular wordpress date formatting

Tags: angular, wordpress, date, formatting

I am using angular to display custom post types, and I used `{{post.date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}` to display date from the post. Now the problem is formatting I get this in return: 2019-03-04 12:02:40.

The formatting is not working.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: you can parse with moment date formate

Comment: Can you give an example of post date and expected result?

Comment: Expected result will be 04/03/2019 thanks